# JQuery add class based on height of element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table in an app with data and the thead element in the table has a variable height depending on what user is logged in and using the application. So sometimes the thead element is narrow in height and sometimes it's much taller. Note that there are only two heights that are possible.

I'd like to somehow use jquery to measure the height of the thead element and then add a class so it might come out like this:

Narrow:

```
<thead class="narrow">
```

Tall:

```
<thead class="tall">
```

I am not even sure if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't short opposite of tall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `height` function

- http://api.jquery.com/height/

With that you can write code like the following

```
var t = $('thead');
t.addClass(t.height() > someValue ? "tall" : "narrow");
```

Comment: This works great! I realized after reading the other answer that it should have been "short" and not "narrow". I can now theme the thead per these two specialized classes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what logic you want, but you can specify a selector to make a jQuery object out of the thead element and then use the `.height()` and `.width()` methods to get it's size:

```
var t = $("thead");
if (t.height() > x) {
    t.addClass("tall");
} else {
    t.addClass("narrow");
}
```

You can obviously use any logic comparing the height and width to each other or to an absolute number.

FYI, `tall` and `narrow` are not typically opposites (they can often both be true at the same time).  I think of `tall` vs. `short` as opposites along with and `narrow` vs. `wide`.